# Make `cp` choose no when prompted to overwrite

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

I have a list of files that I am copying around for various purposes. What my current command looks similar to this:

```
cat list_of_files | xargs -I {} /bin/cp -f {} /destination/dir
```

I am using the full path to `cp` so that the default alias of `cp -i` does not take effect. However, when I find a duplicate file, it is overwriting any that have already been copied. What I would like to do is to force `cp` to *not* overwrite and *not* prompt.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the `cp -n` 'noclobber' option.

It doesn't overwrite existing files and overrides a *previous* `-i` option.

Comment: you know, I read that man page 3 times, and it got past me every time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The -n option should not overwrite an existing file.

Comment: and yet it does if you don't use other options like -d.